# Python - How to efficiently write/read a JSON file inside a compressed archive in one go?

Tags: python, json, performance, compression

I am using Python 3.8 and would like to save a dictionary of data into a JSON file that is compressed in an archive ***in one go***, ideally using only the Python Standard Library. For example, this means my data is saved in a file `data.json` that is contained in an archive `compressed_data.zip`.

Right now, this is as far as I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

# Python Standard Library imports

import json
import zlib

# Prepare some data
data: dict = {
    "common_name": "Brongersma's short-tailed python",
    "scientific_name": "Python brongersmai",
    "length": 290
}

# Save data to a JSON file
with open("data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_JSON_file: 
    json.dump(data, output_JSON_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

# Open saved JSON then compress it
with open ("data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as input_JSON_file: 
    data: dict = json.load(input_JSON_file)
    # Data needs to be saved as bytes to be compressed
    data_bytes: bytes = json.dumps(data, indent=4).encode("utf-8")
    compressed_data = zlib.compress(data_bytes, level=zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
    with open ("compressed_data.zip" , "wb") as output_zlib_file: 
        output_zlib_file.write(compressed_data)
```

This does not produce my desired results because **(a)** it saves the JSON file first, opens it, *then* saves the data into a compressed file ending up with *two* files on disk; and **(b)** the compressed file is the compressed *data* but not a JSON file in a ZIP file that can be opened in any generic GUI compression/decompression program.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to achieve my goal in one go without saving a JSON file first then compressing that into an archive? (i.e. the `.json` file never touches the disk, only the `.zip` file does)
2. *How do I do the reverse* and decompress from an archive directly into a dictionary in Python?
3. If there isn't a way to to 1. and 2. in one go, what would be a relatively efficient way to do it anyway?

Note: Ideally I'd like a solution that only uses the Python 3.8 Standard Library and the compressed archive doesn't have to use the `zlib` library or be a ZIP file. *Other high compression ratio methods are fine, too*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Finally figured it out. Recording it here for future reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later

# Python's internal `zipfile` module
import json
import zipfile

# Prepare some data
data: dict = {
    "common_name": "Brongersma's short-tailed python",
    "scientific_name": "Python brongersmai",
    "length": 290
}

# Use the `zipfile` module
# `compresslevel` was added in Python 3.7
with zipfile.ZipFile("compressed_data.zip", mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9) as zip_file: 
    # Dump JSON data
    dumped_JSON: str = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    # Write the JSON data into `data.json` *inside* the ZIP file
    zip_file.writestr("data.json", data=dumped_JSON)
    # Test integrity of compressed archive
    zip_file.testzip()
```

This solution uses the Python Standard Library's internal [`zipfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). Key is `zip_file.writestr()` which allows you to essentially write to a file *inside* the ZIP file.

If there are other solutions, please do share them!

Comment: I tried a similar method using the same library methods, however the compression on my zipped `.json` was only about 1/3 (versus about 1/10 when using 7-zip).  Still looking for a good way to compress `.json` objects efficiently with python.

Comment: Never mind, glossed over the `compresslevel=9` argument.  Leaving my comment in case someone else was boneheaded like me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little module I put together to read/write json directly to/from a zip.

```py
import json
from codecs import getwriter
from typing import IO
from zipfile import ZIP_DEFLATED, ZipFile

class ZipFileWrapper(ZipFile):
    def open(self, name="data", mode="r", pwd=None, **kwargs):
        return super().open(name=name, mode=mode, pwd=pwd, **kwargs)

    def read(self):
        return super().read(name="data")

def _json_dump_bytes(fp: IO, obj):
    StreamWriter = getwriter("utf-8")
    return json.dump(fp=StreamWriter(fp), obj=obj)

def json_dump_zip(fp: IO, obj):
    with ZipFileWrapper(
        fp, mode="w", compression=ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=9
    ) as zip_file:
        with zip_file.open(mode="w") as _fp:
            _json_dump_bytes(fp=_fp, obj=obj)


def json_load_zip(fp: IO):
    with ZipFileWrapper(fp, mode="r") as zip_file:
        return json.load(zip_file)
```

Usage:

```py
obj = {"foo": "bar"}

with open("my_file.zip", "wb") as f:
    json_dump_zip(fp=f, obj=obj)

with open("my_file.zip", "rb") as f:
    loaded_obj = json_load_zip(fp=f)
```

Details:

It works by leveraging a `codec._StreamWriter` as an intermediary to write bytes-like IO directly from a string input. This circumvents the reason why you can't dump directly to a zip file - since `json.dump` writes unicode, not bytes as is required by `ZipFile`.

Implementation detail:

I've named the json file inside the zip `"data"`. That is because for my implementation I only needed to compress a single json file, and the name of the file is irrelevant for my purpose. Edit as you wish!